# Dynamics CRM SDK using CrmSvcUtil to generate strongly typed entities inherhiting from a different base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a way to create early bound entity classes with the code generation tool that derive from a base class other than Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity?

For example, we are using CrmSvcUtil.exe to generate entities such as

```
public partial class Account : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity
```

However it would be better for these entities to derive from a base class:

```
public partial class Account : BaseEntity

public class BaseEntity : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity
```

How can I do this using CrmSvcUtil.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with the standard CrmvSvcUtil.exe, but the application can be extended, here the relevant MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547384.aspx

Comment: This is what we are using to determine which entities to generate. Do you know how to modify the code writer to change the inerhitance structure above?